# Android : Calling images from drawable and displaying on the screen

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-image

I am designing a Image Puzzle(JigSaw) game. I am stuck in a problem that, when I start the game it shows the option "New Image" but, when I click on that, it gives an error message, means images from the drawable folder are not loading.

I did research and i came with this, i have implemented this in my code. but, it gives an error.. "Could not Load."

```
    protected void newImage()
{
    LinkedList<Uri> availableImages = new LinkedList<Uri>();


    findInternalImages(availableImages);

    if(availableImages.isEmpty())
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.error_could_not_load_image), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }

    int index = new Random().nextInt(availableImages.size());
    loadBitmap(availableImages.get(index));
}

protected void findInternalImages(List<Uri> list)
{

    Field[] fields = R.drawable.class.getFields();


    for(Field field: fields)
    {
        //String name = field.getName();

        //if(name.startsWith(FILENAME_IMAGE_PREFIX))
        //{
            //int id = getResources().getIdentifier(name, "drawable", getPackageName());
    for(int j=1;j<13;j++)
    {
            Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(getResources()
                      .getIdentifier("image_"+j, "drawable", getPackageName()));

    }
        //}
    }
}
```

My Problem is,
when i run the program it should show images from drawable folder and when i choose the one then actual scrambling should start. so, one can play the jig saw game.

Comment: please don't consider `first 3 lines of findinternalimages`

Answer (score 1):

Start by checking that your images are in a Android compatible format, that was causing me problems to begin with. I normally stick to .png now.

This is the code you will need to modify the image

```
ImageView pwrSwap = (ImageView) beaconitems.findViewById(R.id.yourImageID);
pwrSwap.setImageResource(R.drawable.yourImage);
```

http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

Comment: Add in the layout that you are using.

Comment: Means?? can't get you? will you please elaborate?

Comment: Provide the XML layout that you are drawing to. Please also post the logcat errors because ti will make it easier to identify the problem.

Comment: Are you still having troubles with this issue, please close the issue by confirming the answer or providing your resolution.